# Naming of Rest API

Tags: rest, http, asp.net-web-api2, asp.net-web-api-routing

I know it's not a highly technical question.But I need some suggestions. 
I know there are some conventions for naming Rest APIs.
I have a requirement to create a Rest API by Asp.Net Web API. The service is to retrieve all schools that near by the user location. 
Inputs: User Latitude, Longitude, Distance

How can I name the URL.

```
api/v1/Schools/Near,

api/v1/NearbySchools
```

I know its better to use GET: `api/v1/Schools`
But may be in future the number of inputs changes, So it better to make as POST.
POST: `api/v1/Schools`
But this also have problem. I have already a URL like this to create a new School.

Please help me. I know its not a technical one but I would like to follow the conventions.

Comment: follow a single convention throughout the project. You can also try like `Retrieve/SchoolsNearBY` means `<TypeOfMethod>/<functionality>`

Answer (score 1):

Different patterns are being used by the developers to make REST API.

```
api/v1/Schools
```

With query params is apt as per the requirement. With a limitation about the length of input.

In such cases, POST method with desired input, that can be extended to any number of search criteria with request body.

```
api/v1/Schools/search
```

The following are in practice.

- /schools - POST - create
- /schools - GET  - get all schools
- /schools/{schoolid} - GET - Get a particular school
- /schools/{schoolid} - PUT - Update
- /schools/{schoolid} - DELETE - Delete a school
- /schools/search - POST - search for a school based on search criteria

You can use [HATEOAS](https://spring.io/understanding/HATEOAS) as the describer of your REST API so that the consumers of the API will have the documented structure.

Comment: Hi @VinayVeluri - Thanks for the response.
Let's say I need an action that let a client marks a school as "public" or "private". It is basically an 'edit' action but it doesn't really edit the whole "school" entity. Either way, I need the PUT URL for real edit action. 
What is your suggestion for this type of URL. I could go with:

`PUT /schools/{schoolid}/public-private`  

which receive a simple value or a small jason in the body of the PUT request, or what?